# knockoutjs set select default selected value

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I'm using knockout.js and trying to set the default value (not use optionCaption) of my select binding as well as capture the value when anyone changes it.

```
<div class="customization-container" data-bind="foreach: customization">
    <div class="clear-both option">
        <label data-bind="text: Name"></label>
        <select data-bind="options: AvailableValues, value: Value></select>
    </div>
</div>
```

What I have in AvailableValues is an array like [1, 2, 3, 4] or ["Row", "Run", "Paddle", "Ski"] and I want to be able to pick which one of the values is the default.

I can't find anything in the knockout.js documentation or online yet. I don't want to set a caption, I want the default to be a literal value from the array.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're doing it just the way you should (apart from a missing double quote to close your `data-bind` attribute). See this example:

```js
var vm = {
  AvailableValues: [1,2,3],
  Value: ko.observable(2)
};

ko.applyBindings(vm);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<select data-bind="options: AvailableValues, value: Value"></select>
```

Which would work equally fine for a list of strings:

```js
var vm = {
  AvailableValues: ["Row", "Run", "Paddle", "Ski"],
  Value: ko.observable("Paddle")
};

ko.applyBindings(vm);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<select data-bind="options: AvailableValues, value: Value"></select>
```